# WPF Width of Expander's ScrollViewer content

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, expander

I have the following hierarchy of components, denoted with IDs to alleviate confusion:

```
|>ScrollViewer[1]
|->StackPanel
|-->Expander[2]
|--->ScrollViewer[3]
|---->StackPanel
|----->Button
```

The issue here is that I want [3]'s width to be bound to [1]'s width.
In my code I do this thusly:

```
Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TimeScrollViewer, Converter={converters:ScalarConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.95'}"
```

The converter simply scales the value by 0.95.

Now, this *partially* works in that [3] (red outline) can be scrolled over that entire width, however only the portion that is within [2]'s width is ever visible (dotted outline).

A video to display the undesirable behavior:
https://youtu.be/_Qw9W0sGfP4

[image]

The XAML:

```
<s:SurfaceScrollViewer Name="TimeScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ItemsControl Name="TimeItemsControl">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Expanded="ExpanderExpanded" Collapsed="ExpanderCollapsed" Header="{Binding Header}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TimeScrollViewer, Converter={converters:ScalarConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.2'}">
                    <s:SurfaceScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TimeScrollViewer, Converter={converters:ScalarConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.95'}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GuestList}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <s:SurfaceButton Content="{Binding GuestName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TimeScrollViewer, Converter={converters:ScalarConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.15'}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
```

How can I get the ScrollViewer to properly fill that red outline?

Answer (score 2):

Forget trying to bind widths of elements together. Just set the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ItemsControl` to stretch the children horizontally:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! That appears to work, I don't aim to fully stretch the ScrollViewer because I want to maintain the padding I've got here:
http://i.imgur.com/EMTnR1E.png

Now, however, I have an issue of the Expander's Header not being the 20% width of the outer-most ScrollViewer.

Comment: Just use Margin/Padding to separate controls with a fixed amount of space, or Grid's with columns/rows to separate things with a relative amount of space.